# Run Executable Without WScript

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file, vbscript, citrix

**I have the following problem:**

- When a user logs on over citrix, the logon script writes to a network file
- Once the file has been written to, notify the local machine so that it can perform some operations
- Once this is done, restart the session (I know how to do this part, my difficulty is with monitoring a network file from a locally stored FileWatcher and then running a local exe)

**I plan to achieve this by:**

- Registering an `ActiveEventScriptConsumer` on the machine, which will monitor a file and then run an executable once it is modified
- The first actions the exe takes is to sleep for 5 minutes, and then perform the actions I need it to do

**Constraints**

The issue I have is that `ActiveEventScriptConsuemr`s can't use the `Wscript` object, meaning I can't run an exe with:

`objShell.Run("C:\MyProgram.exe")`

Is there some other way of running an executable from vbscript which can be done from an `EventConsumer`? Alternatively, am I able to register this subscription where the script run uses something other than VBScript?

I would include the `Wait` in my logons script, but I can't delay the end of this because this causes my group policies to run 5 minutes after logon!

I tried having a look at running a batch file from the VBS, but this also uses `WScript`.

The executable is checking for something which occurs when a (Citrix) session begins, so I can't use regular windows logon as a trigger because sometimes the user will log onto a session even though the machine itself has been logged on for some time.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Event Subscription Code:**

```
$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$query = @"
SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Name='C:\\test\\filewatching\\tester.txt'
"@
$instanceFilter = ([WMICLASS]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()
$instanceFilter.QueryLanguage = 'WQL'
$instanceFilter.Query = $query
$instanceFilter.Name = 'EventFilterNameHere'
$instanceFilter.EventNameSpace = 'root/CIMV2'
$result = $instanceFilter.Put()

$script = 
@"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test\filewatching\Log.log", 8, True)
objFile.WriteLine "1"

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("C:\MyProgran.exe")
Set objShell = Nothing

objFile.WriteLine "2"

objFile.Close
"@
$instanceConsumer = ([wmiclass]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer").CreateInstance()
$instanceConsumer.Name = 'ConsumerNameHere'
$instanceConsumer.ScriptingEngine = 'VBScript'
$instanceConsumer.ScriptFilename = '' 
$instanceConsumer.ScriptText = $script
$instanceConsumer.Put()

[object]$Filter = (Get-WMIObject -Computername $Computername -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventFilter | Sort Name)
[object]$Consumer = (Get-WMIObject -Computername $Computername -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventConsumer | Sort Name)

$instanceBinding = ([wmiclass]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance()
$instanceBinding.Filter = $Filter
$instanceBinding.Consumer = $Consumer
$instanceBinding.Put()
```

Comment: How about using a scheduled task? Set trigger to logon and add a five minute delay.

Comment: @vonPryz That is a good idea. Is there a way of triggering at a logon to a citrix session rather than a logon to the pc itself?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What problem are you solving?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Hi bill, my problem is as follows: When a user logs in over Citrix, I need the local machine to be notified of this so that it can run a local application (this local program will alert the user and perform some operations before restarting the session). So my plan is to update a network file when the user logs in remotely, and have a filewatcher sitting on the localmachine to monitor this file and execute my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using this type of event consumer. This is because the `ActiveScriptEventConsumer` doesn't allow any screen interaction except for basic message boxes:

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384749(v=vs.85).aspx)

> When WMI is run as a service, scripts run by ActiveScriptEventConsumer do not generate screen output. Scripts that use MsgBox do run, but they do not display information on the screen. Running the WMI service as an executable file is not supported, but WMI allows scripts that use the MsgBox function to display output or accept user input. None of the methods provided by the WScript object can be used because ActiveScriptEventConsumer does not use Windows Script Host (WSH).

Another option would be to use `CSCript`, which only uses the command line, but this also doesn't support visual activity (only command-line), so for my purposes this will not work.